# How to save fields that are not part of form but required in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with a field that is required but not entered by the user and i have a hard time saving the model without errors. My model definition looks like this:

```
class Goal(db.Model):
  author = db.UserProperty(required=True)
  description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True, required=True)
  active = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class GoalForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Goal
    exclude = ['author', 'active']
```

And i use django-forms in appengine to create and validate the form. When i try to save the result of this form however....

```
  def post(self):

    data = GoalForm(data=self.request.POST)

    if data.is_valid():

      goal = data.save(commit=False)
      goal.author = users.get_current_user()

      goal.put()
      self.redirect('/')
```

I get "ValueError: The Goal could not be created (Property author is required)"

Now i would think that by having commit=False, then adding the property for Goal, and then saving the object would allow me to do this but obviously it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: If the author is not actually required, why do you have required=True? Sorry I'm just trying to get some context here.

Comment: the author is required but it's a property i want to set myself. i basically don't want any goals without authors ending up in the datastore, the interface should not allow it but i would still like to check fo it. i might be going about that the wrong way, i'm a django newbie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that save() will raise a ValueError if the data in the form doesn't validate

You can find what you need about the save() method here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

**Edit:** Instead of goal.put(), do a goal.save()

**Edit2:** This should solve your problem:

```
goal = Goal(author='Mr') #example
data = GoalForm(data=self.request.POST, instance=goal)
```

Comment: this is where i found how to add more properties before committing, but it does not say what to do in my particular case as far as i could tell. completing the model first and than passing that as an instance to the GoalForm fails with a similar error..

Comment: Try doing a goal.save(), not a goal.put()

Comment: aha ok thanks! tried it but i'm afraid that results in the same error: "ValueError: The Goal could not be created (Property author is required)"

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but for the sake of others searching for a similar answer, I'm posting the following:

Unless there's a reason I missed for not doing so, but I believe this is what you need:

```
class Goal(db.Model):
  author = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
  ...
  ...
```

For reference:
[Types and Property Classes:class UserProperty()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#UserProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Your GoalForm should inherit from django.forms.ModelForm and be defined such that it only requires some fields:

```
class GoalForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Goal
        fields = ('description', 'etc')
```

Not sure if this is totally working in AppEngine though.

You should also save the form (still not sure about AppEngine):

```
data = GoalForm(data=self.request.POST)

if data.is_valid():
  data.author = users.get_current_user()
  data.put()
```

Comment: yeah i do inherit djangoforms, i added my GoalForm to make that more clear, this should work in appengine from what i gather. except perhaps for this special case?

Comment: data.put() wont's work since i will have to save() the form (which validates it) first and then use that data to put() the goal in the datastore.

i did try simply adding the data.author = users.get_current_user() before i save it but that doesn't work. i basically have to get that author into the form data before i save it and it gets validated.